# React Material UI Mode Change Text Color Change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this button on my page that changes the theme on the page from dark to light.
[image]

Text changes to white and background changes to black then I click again vice-versa. I did not specifically gave a color prop or background prop to any element but everything works. The problem is with the below buttons

[image]

As you see they are red and coming from primary.light, though when the dark theme active it needs to be primary.dark but it doesn't...

```
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: mode,
      primary: {
        light: "#FF0000",
        main: "#3f50b5",
        dark: "#002884",
        contrastText: "#FF0000"
      },
      secondary: {
        light: "#ff7961",
        main: "#f44336",
        dark: "#ba000d",
        contrastText: "#000"
      }
    },
    typography: {
      useNextVariants: true
    }
  });
```

Comment: I think more code is needed to accurately diagnose the issue here. Could you share the components? Maybe link a CodeSandbox?